# Pivot Pandas DataFrame switching Index and Column Names

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table that was generated like this, to my understanding the index to the table is the (APPLE,BANANA,PEAR,ORANGE)

```
           INFO
APPLE      YUMMY
BANANA     5                                           
PEAR       GREEN                                            
ORANGE     {COLOR:ORANGE}
```

I want to convert(pivot) my table to look like

```
       APPLE   BANANA   PEAR     ORANGE
INFO   YUMMY   5        GREEN    {COLOR:ORANGE}
```

Where INFO is the only index and there are 4 columns

How would I be able to pivot this table? (with pivot() / pivot_table() im assuming)

Comment: You probably want the [transpose](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built in DataFrame.transpose -- your transformation will look as follows:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
                  INFO
APPLE            YUMMY
BANANA               5
PEAR             GREEN
ORANGE  {COLOR:ORANGE}

In [2]: df_transposed = df.transpose()

In [3]: df_transposed
Out[3]:
      APPLE BANANA   PEAR          ORANGE
INFO  YUMMY      5  GREEN  {COLOR:ORANGE}
```

Comment: You can just use [`df.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html#pandas.DataFrame.T) fewer characters to type

Comment: @EdChum: explicit is better then implicit